# FCM iOS device token not working in aws sns push notification

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins, amazon-sns

I created an application in `aws` `sns` for `Apple Development`, used `p12` file for credentials.
I'm using `cordova` app with `phone-gap`.

Formats:

```
# device token format
XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX

# registration id format
abCDEFghijk:AHJGJkhkhkbjkJYJgjkhkjhkjhkkhkhkhkhkjhkGSDH6gjhgHGugkjhgjgGjhgjhghJGjhhj-98jhgjhf-tIE_&jhgfhfjhgjhggfgdhfjhkhlhljxvcxbbm-QjhghGuuhfdgfhjmgjjkg
```

# In aws Examples: this is the format of device token they are getting

59b70e15ca0f24835b49471e74a9a4095ed3d93bd4642c350c33b309d0b29f5b

When I tried to create endpoint application using the above device token I'm getting following error:

```
Invalid parameter:
  Token Reason: iOS device tokens must be no more than 400 hexadecimal characters
  (Service: AmazonSNS;
   Status Code: 400;
   Error Code: InvalidParameter;
   Request ID: 14a9e207-9d0d-55b7-8394-b1ec0eabd59b)
```

I checked with `aws` documentation and they have different device token documentations: check this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html#device-token-apns).

What am i missing??

Is there a way to convert the token in correct format in `c#`?

Comment: Since you mentioned you are using cordova, you might want to check [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=179115)

Comment: Alex, deviceToken format i'm getting is UUID but the format mentioned in the post you shared and in aws example is 64 bit hex string. That is the reason i'm getting error.

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Comment: @simo As i told in the answer, i was registering iOS device in FCM and using that registration id, so it caused the issue. Once i started to register my iOS devices to APNS, issue got solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using APNS for iOS. I was trying to register FCM generated device token into APNS. Once I changed it, I started to get device token in required format.